# Modify expression to only match absolute string

Tags: python, regex

I have this list of phrases and dictionary below:

```
phrases = ['leed','i am good', 'going to the market', 'eating cookies']

dictionary = {'http://www.firsturl.com': 'i am going to the market and tomorrow will be eating cookies',
             'http://www.secondurl.com': 'tomorrow is my birthday and i shall be', 
             'http://www.thirdurl.com': 'i am good and will go to sleep bleeding'}
```

The below code gives the desired result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'urls': list(dictionary.keys()), 'strings': list(dictionary.values())})
pattern = '|'.join(phrases)

s = df.pop('strings').str.findall(pattern)
df = df.assign(phrasecount=s.str.len(), phrase=s.map(', '.join))
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='phrasecount') if df['phrasecount'].eq(0).all() else df[df['phrasecount'].ne(0)]
```

However, 'leed' should not be a match in the 3rd url. it's matching due to bleeding. I want only absolute match.

Comment: hang on i got answer for yiu. oh you have to join all together to examine oderwise cant help

Comment: the dupr generalties wont help a bit, show the resultant strings and get an answer in a minute